# What is most preferred way to center align text like this without using line break <br>?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

What is most preferred way to center align text like this without using line break `<br>`?

[image]

Comment: If your text is going to show up this ugly and unreadable, you might as well just use `<br>`.

Comment: I can't really understand what `<br>` has to do with horizontal alignment :-?

Answer (score 4):

If a line break means a line break, then `<br>` is the appropriate tag.  And in this case, the text has line breaks in it, so just use `<br>` tags.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I know it's nothing wrong with `<br>` but on wider screen it will not look like this. thats why I don't want to  do by `<br>`. I got two designs from client one is for 768 px and one is for unlimited width. and in 768px version client want the text like this

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't look like this on a wider screen? Can you give an example?

Comment: Maybe describe your goal a bit better then...  Because all we have to go on is that you want to insert line breaks after certain words, which you use `<br>`s to do.  If your goal is simply to center text in a container, then dont use any `<br>` tags at all.  I'm not so sure you have actually described your issue here.

Comment: @Juhana - In big monitor text is in only 3 lines, but in screensize of upto 768px client want to preset text like this.

Comment: Can't you let the browser do the line breaking automatically?

Comment: @Juhana - Client don't understand it. for my personal site I will not do like this.

Comment: All I can tell you at this point is either use `<br>` or put the text in a fixed width container and simply let it wrap.  But if you put in `<br>` tags in a fluid width container then it will wrap strangely on small screens.  So fixed width or `<br>` tags, choose one.

Comment: @Jitendra: br is there for a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do it without it. The text only wraps to the next line if it is needed. Its not needed here so cannot. Just use `<br>`. Its ok to do that